# Make svn automatically detect diff-cmd and diff3-cmd depending on file extension

Tags: svn

In Git one can specify these in `.gitattributes` and perform some additional configuration:

```
git config diff.difftool.command ...
git config merge.mergetool.driver ...
```

In Mercurial it is possible to specify patterns in `hgrc` file (`[diff-patterns]` and `[merge-patterns]` sections).

How to achieve this in Subversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [red-book for Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externaldifftools) (normally the source of all knowledge) is not too specific here. It names that there is the option to configure `diff-cmd` and `diff3-cmd` and that it is possible to add extensions to the call.

However, it states the following:

> The decision on when to fire off a contextual two- or three-way diff as part of a larger Subversion operation is made entirely by Subversion and is affected by, among other things, whether the files being operated on are human-readable as determined by their svn:mime-type property. This means, for example, that even if you had the niftiest Microsoft Word-aware differencing or merging tool in the universe, it would never be invoked by Subversion as long as your versioned Word documents had a configured MIME type that denoted that they were not human-readable (such as application/msword).

It does not say how to influence that decision :-(

If you are using the tool TortoiseSVN, there are configuration options included to specify the used diff tool per mime-type of the file under consideration. The path to that configuration is: `TortoiseSVN > Settings > External Programs > Diff Viewer > Advanced...`. Perhaps that is an option for you.

---

My personal opinion here is that the subversion team thinks that you should use a wrapper as diff-tool anyway, and to do there the decision what tool to use with which specific configuration based on the mime-type.